# Css3 different keyframes for different states

Tags: css, hover, css-animations

i've got some trouble with this
My first animation works fine when the page loads, but i want to trigger another animation when you hover the figure element, if you do this, the first animation repeats, but apparently,if you put the mouse over the red box and force it to go to the original position, then my second animation works :/

Is that with keyframes the element belongs to its first position ? i made it absolute and is the same thing.
You can see the working code here:
http://jsfiddle.net/zhk7w/
Thanks for the hand!

```
<div id="wrapper">
        <article>
            <div id="sharing-wrapper">
                <figure>
                <a class="animate" href="#">p</a>
                </figure>

            </div>
            <div class="test">
                <a class="test" href="">C</a>
            </div>
        </article>
    </div>
```

And the css :

```
#sharing-wrapper figure{
margin-left: 50px;
position: relative;
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
}
#sharing-wrapper figure{
padding: 15px;
background-color: red;
position: relative;
-webkit-animation-name:animatetopbottom,animateleft;
-webkit-animation-duration:3s,3s;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
/*-webkit-animation-direction:alternate;*/
}
#sharing-wrapper figure:hover{
-webkit-animation: shakeit 1s;}
```

The animations :

```
    @-webkit-keyframes animateleft{
    from {left: 0px;}
    to {left: 50px;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes animatetopbottom{
    0% {top: 0px;}
    10% {top: 90px;}
    20% {top: 60px;-webkit-transform:rotate(680grad);}
    30% {top: 90px;-webkit-transform:scale(0.7);}
    40% {-webkit-transform:scale(1.5);}
    50% {top: 60px;-webkit-transform:rotate(0grad);}
    80% {top: 80px;}
    100% {top: 80px;}

}



    @-webkit-keyframes shakeit{
    from { top: 25px; }
    to { top: -40px; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you shoulde give a delay to animation before they take hover.

Once you hover your box, it shifts away from the mouse and :hover is not an active state anymore, next or defaut animation takes over right away :
http://jsfiddle.net/zhk7w/1/

```
#sharing-wrapper figure{
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-animation-delay:1s;
    -webkit-animation-name:animatetopbottom,animateleft;
    -webkit-animation-duration:3s,3s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
    /*-webkit-animation-direction:alternate;*/
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time :D .. that aids, the things is that after the first animation, i want the box to stay where it finished , and that the hover animation occurs in the same place where the first animation  finished, i gave it absolute position, but the box returns to its original position :/

Comment: tip: When animation is finished, original rules are not overwritten anymore.